# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json ...'

Tags: json, vb.net, console, package, nuget

When trying to run my VB.NET MVC4 application I receive the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
file specified.
```

I cannot locate this package in my reference list whatsoever.

Comment: Install that package from NuGet.

Comment: @SLaks all the instructions are for VS2010 and I cannot find the menu options in 2012

Comment: @SLaks Had to do a lot to get it going, steps shown in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many steps to get this Newtonsoft.Json installed since Tools > Nuget Package Manager did not exist in my VS 2012 instance.

1) Uninstall Nuget

a) Rename the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions folder to Extensions_old

b) Run the uninstaller from Control Panel > Uninstall a Program

2) Reinstall Nuget using the .VSIX file from their website (do not use VS 2012)

3) Open the solution and run Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console

4) Run `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`